# ROOM database: insert static data before other CRUD operations

Tags: android, android-room

I have a question about adding static data (taskPriority) to the database. From what I understand, the right way to insert data on database create is to use RoomDatabase.Callback. However, when the app runs the first time and I insert a task (a task has taskPriority.id as a foreign key), it seems that the task is being inserted before taskPriority has a chance to be inserted from the callback. My question is: How do I make it so that taskPriority is inserted before task is inserted? Both taskPriorityDao.insert() and taskDao.insert() run on a separate thread (with ExecutorService).

```
    public static TaskRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (null == INSTANCE) {
            synchronized (TaskRoomDatabase.class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.getApplicationContext(),
                        TaskRoomDatabase.class,
                                DATABASE_NAME)
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static final RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback =
            new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                    databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
                        TaskPriorityDao taskPriorityDao = INSTANCE.taskPriorityDao();
                        taskPriorityDao.deleteAll();

                        TaskPriority taskPriority = new TaskPriority(Priority.HIGH, "HIGH");
                        taskPriorityDao.insert(taskPriority);

                        taskPriority = new TaskPriority(Priority.MEDIUM, "MEDIUM");
                        taskPriorityDao.insert(taskPriority);

                        taskPriority = new TaskPriority(Priority.LOW, "LOW");
                        taskPriorityDao.insert(taskPriority);
                    });
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest NOT using functions from the class(es) annotated with @Dao but to instead use the **[SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase)** methods *(hence why the SupportSQLiteDatabase is passed)*.

A little more work BUT they will be done sequentially and in the order in which they are invoked.

Something along the lines of

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.delete("the_appropriate_table_name",null,null);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name", Priority.HIGH);
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name","HIGH");
    db.insert("the_appropriate_table_name", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
    cv.clear();
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name",Priority.MEDIUM);
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name","MEDIUM");
    db.insert("the_appropriate_table_name", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
    cv.clear();
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name",Priority.LOW);
    cv.put("the_respective_column_name","LOW");
    db.insert("the_appropriate_table_name", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
```

- see [delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D))
- see [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.content.ContentValues))
- see [ContentValues](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)

  - 1 `put` per column, for the columns that require a value (e.g. if an id column that is expected to be generated, then omit such a column, like for a column that is meant to have a default value supplied *(this latter case is typically a rare case with Room)*)
- **Note** values that are descriptive *(those with appropriate/respective)* should be replaced accordingly based upon the TaskPriority class.
- `beginTransaction` starts a transaction, `endTransaction` will rollback the changes unless `setTransactionSuccessful` precedes it (should ideally immediately precede the `endTrasnaction`).
- doing all in a single transaction will be more efficient as instead of the 4 transactions and therefore 4 disk writes, there will only be the single disk write.

**Demo** (using a pre-existing project adapted)

In this project the @Entity annotated class is :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "photos")
public class MyImages {
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   public int image_id;
   public String image_title;
   public String image_description;
   public byte[] image;

   public MyImages(String image_title, String image_description, byte[] image) {
      this.image_title = image_title;
      this.image_description = image_description;
      this.image = image;
   }

   public void setImage_id(int image_id) {
      this.image_id = image_id;
   }

   public int getImage_id() {
      return image_id;
   }

   public String getImage_title() {
      return image_title;
   }

   public String getImage_description() {
      return image_description;
   }

   public byte[] getImage() {
      return image;
   }
}
```

i.e. 4 columns in the photos table, the callabck created for the demo :-

```
static Callback cb = new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
     super.onCreate(db);
     db.beginTransaction();
     ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     cv.put("image_id",1000);
     cv.put("image_title","not an image");
     cv.put("image_description","The image's description is ....");
     cv.put("image",new byte[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});
     db.insert("photos", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
     db.endTransaction();
  }

  @Override
  public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
     super.onOpen(db);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
     super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
  }
};
```

- So just a single row added but NOTE an id has been provided rather than have it generated setting the id to 1000.

When run then the database (which has 2 other rows added in the main activity) is:-

[image]

- the 2 other rows have generated id's that follow on from the initial 1000

  - *(note I do not advocate the use of `autoGenerate = true` it's just that the code had this and hence it's inclusion, likewise I do not advocate the use of int's for id's long's should really be used)*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `createFromAsset()` and it seems to work.

Also found the following on creating a sqlite file:
https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-package-003