# (Android) When is the initial data stored in the Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm currently trying to set up some initial data in the `Room database`.

As a result, the initial data setup was successful, but `App Inspection` confirmed that the data is saved only when `getWorkoutList()`.

To explain in more detail, the initial data is not saved with the insert function alone, and the initial data is saved in the DB only when a function that calls the DB data called `getWorkoutList()` is executed from the `ViewModel`.

When the database is created in the view model, I expected the initial data to be saved only with the insert function. But it wasn't.

Why is the initial data not saved with only the insert function?

---

The following is the DB status in App inspection according to the function call.

***1. When only `insertWorkoutList(data)` is executed***

- There is no `DB and table` creation, and no initial data is saved.

[image]

***2. When only `getWokroutList()` is executed.***

- DB and table are created, but there is no data.

[image]

[image]

***3. When both are executed.***

- Initial data is normally saved.

[image]

---

**Code**

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutListDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM WorkoutList")
    suspend fun getWorkoutList() : WorkoutList

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertWorkoutList(workoutList: WorkoutList)
}
```

**WorkoutListDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [WorkoutList::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(WorkoutListTypeConverter::class)
abstract class WorkoutListDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun workoutListDao() : WorkoutListDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE : WorkoutListDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : WorkoutListDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WorkoutListDatabase::class.java,
                    "workoutlist_db"
                )
                    .addCallback(WorkoutListCallback(context))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkoutListCallback**

```
class WorkoutListCallback(private val context: Context) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            fillWithStartingWorkoutList(context)
        }
    }

    private fun fillWithStartingWorkoutList(context: Context) {
        val dao = WorkoutListDatabase.getDatabase(context).workoutListDao()

        try {
            val data = loadJsonData(context)
//            dao.insertWorkoutList(data)

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun loadJsonData(context: Context) : WorkoutList {
        val assetManager = context.assets
        val inputStream = assetManager.open(WORKOUTLIST_JSON_FILE)
        
        BufferedReader(inputStream.reader()).use { reader ->
            val gson = Gson()
            return gson.fromJson(reader, WorkoutList::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val workoutDao = WorkoutListDatabase.getDatabase(application).workoutListDao()
    private val workoutListRepo = WorkoutListRepository(workoutDao)

    
    fun setList(part : BodyPart) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            workoutListRepo.getWorkoutList()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback will only be called when the database is actually accessed NOT when an instance of the @Database annotated class is obtained.

As such the database is not created by:-

```
val dao = WorkoutListDatabase.getDatabase(context).workoutListDao()
```

but is created by

```
workoutListRepo.getWorkoutList()
```

That is the actual relatively resource hungry action of opening the database is left until it is definitely needed.

A get around could be to use :-

```
    fun getDatabase(context: Context) : WorkoutListDatabase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                WorkoutListDatabase::class.java,
                "workoutlist_db"
            )
                .addCallback(WorkoutListCallback(context))
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase() //<<<<< FORCE OPEN
            instance
        }
    }
```

This would then force an open of the database and if it does not actually exist then the overidden `onCreate` method will be invoked. **However,this (I think) would be done on the main thread, which you do not want.**

I would strongly suggest NOT using functions from the @Dao annotated class(es) especially if they have suspend as you then may have no control over when the threads will run.

Instead you should use the [SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase) passed to the function, it has many methods e.g. you would likely use the **[insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.content.ContentValues))** method.

see [ROOM database: insert static data before other CRUD operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400062/room-database-insert-static-data-before-other-crud-operations/72400960#72400960) for an example where the order was an issue. The example includes the conversion of the actions to utilise the intended SupportSQLiteDatabase methods.

You may notice that the example includes placing all the database changes into a single transaction, which is more efficient as instead of each individual action (insert/delete in the example) writing to disk, the entire transaction (all actions) are written to disk once.

Comment: As you said, using `instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` , I confirmed that `DB` creation and `initial data` were set only with `insertWorkoutList(data)` without `getWokroutList()`.
But is this a bad way? And is it wrong that the initial data is saved when `getWokroutList()`, which is the way I am currently doing, is called?

Comment: @ybybyb ***But is this a bad way?*** Not really as it makes sense to defer the actual and resource heavy open until it is definitely needed. ***is it wrong that the initial data is saved when getWokroutList(), which is the way I am currently doing, is called?*** No just confusing for those unaware of the underlying process.

Comment: Ummm...it's a bit difficult. So, can I continue using the same method (using `DAO`)? Or is it better to use `execSQL` or `insert()` with the `SupportSQLiteDatabase` parameter of `onCreate()` as you said?

Comment: @ybybyb I'd say it is better to use the passed SupportSQLiteDatabase as it is called/invoked in the initiating thread so the processing is sequential albeit it not as easy. You also have access to methods that can improve matters, such as the `beginTransaaction` -> `setTransactionSuccessful` if all is good -> `endTransaction` sequence, which can reduce multiple resource expensive disk writes to a single disk write. Simply put you have more control when using SupportSQLiteDatabase.

Comment: I don't know what `beginTransaaction, setTransactionSuccessful,endTransaction` mean, but I know it's roughly more efficient.

By the way, if you look at the example link you posted, you can see that you use `put()` to set the column data one by one. This part seems more complicated, is it unavoidable?

Comment: @ybybyb Avoidable you could use the `execSQL` method but then you have to write the SQL e.g. `INSERT INTO the_table VALUES('a',1,);` (see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). The `insert`, `delete` and `update` methods are convenience methods that take parameters and build the underlying SQL. `ContentValues` assist with the column/value pairing and even more complicated value binding (see https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). Binding protects against SQL Injection and properly encloses the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot. But I'm sorry, but I'll ask you one thing separately.. Is there a `bug` in `Room` that doesn't save to `DB`?
After asking you a question, I try again today, and the data is not saved unless I force open the `DB` with `instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()`. Of course, there is no `DB creation`.
The code is the same and I don't know why.